# How to show a NSObject as a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

I read on StackOverflow that to create a messaging speech bubble, the TTSpeechBubbleShape class is highly recommended.

[Speech Bubble in iOS SDK using Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196112/speech-bubble-in-ios-sdk-using-objective-c/11196172#11196172)

However, this class is derived from a custom NSObject class, so I have no idea how to turn this NSObject and add it into one of the cells of my custom UITableView class?

**So, how does one turn a NSObject into a UIView? (Or at least show a NSObject as part of a UIView)**

Thanks from a first time iOS app developer.

More info on the class:
http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_speech_bubble_shape.php
https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Style/Headers/TTSpeechBubbleShape.h
https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Style/Sources/TTSpeechBubbleShape.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those bubble classes just prepare a path. A path can be drawn in a CGContext. You cannot draw a UIObject in any way. Learn the basics of cocoa touch... read the documentation.

A more easy way for your bubbles is a single resizable image like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196243/407488

Comment: i read the three20 documentation, and I read the UIView and NSObject documentation, but did not find anything useful in those. I guess I will just have to figure out how to make a speech bubble in Photoshop

Comment: just use this class: http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/ (or the images from there)