# how to draw border of UITextView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I need to create an `UITextView` like in Image, but `UITextView` auto resize to content height. It is in chat message. At left-bottom and right-bottom have one arrow. But I don't know how to draw or create them in iOS. Can someone tell me how to do this? thank you very much.

Arrow in left-bottom and turn the left if messsage from another body, arrow on the right-bottom and turn the right when message from "self"

[image]

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196112/speech-bubble-in-ios-sdk-using-objective-c>

follow this Hope will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mirror effect On the image. by using same image for both sender and receiver

```
-(UIImage*)setBubbleImageForSender
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sender.png"];

    return image;
}

-(UIImage*)setBubbleImageForReceiver
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sender.png"];

    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                                scale:image.scale
                          orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    return image;
}
```

The above thing will change the arrow direction for the chat app.

for resizing the height and width you can use the `[imgvw resizableImageWithCapInsets:..]`  for the imageview and set table cell height accordingly.

Thanks