# Custom border around UITextView with arrow

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I need to make UITextView to look like a chat bubble with an arrow.
I know how to change border color, radius, and border width. The problem is that I would like to make the arrow stick out of the bubble. Any ideas how to do that?

I have tried to make custom view with bubble image inside and UITextView inside, but that doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always great to answer your own question... So a whole day i was trying to create that bubble and eventually i ended up creating `UIView` with `UIImageView` and `UITextView` subviews. First thing that helped was using `resizableImageWithCapInsets` like this:

> ```
> switch (self.arrowDirection) {
>     case BUBBLE_ARROW_DIRECTION_LEFT:
>         imageForBubble = [[UIImage
>                            imageNamed:@"chatBoxLeftSmall.png"]
>                           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 50, 30, 30)];
>         break;
>     case BUBBLE_ARROW_DIRECTION_RIGHT:
>         imageForBubble = [[UIImage
>                            imageNamed:@"chatBoxRightSmall.png"]
>                           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30, 40)];
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
> }
> ```

And resizing it using animations like this:

> -(void) setSizeForTextView:(UITextView *)textView
>   {
>       CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
>       CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
>       newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, textView.frame.size.width), newSize.height);

```
if(newFrame.size.height > self.initialTextViewFrame.size.height){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                         animations:^{
                             [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.frame.origin.y,
                                                       kMAX_WIDTH,
                                                       newFrame.size.height+kTXT_VIEW_PADDING_BOTTOM)];
                             [self.bubbleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bubbleImage.frame.origin.x,
                                                                   self.bubbleImage.frame.origin.y,
                                                                   self.bubbleImage.frame.size.width,
                                                                   newFrame.size.height + (kTXT_VIEW_PADDING_BOTTOM - kBUBBLE_IMAGE_PADDING_BOTTOM))];
                             textView.frame = newFrame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];

}else if (newFrame.size.height < self.initialTextViewFrame.size.height){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                         animations:^{
                             [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.frame.origin.y,
                                                       kMAX_WIDTH,
                                                       self.initialViewFrame.size.height)];

                             [self.bubbleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bubbleImage.frame.origin.x,
                                                                   self.bubbleImage.frame.origin.y,
                                                                   self.bubbleImage.frame.size.width,
                                                                   self.initialViewFrame.size.height-kBUBBLE_IMAGE_PADDING_BOTTOM)];
                             textView.frame = newFrame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             textView.frame = self.initialTextViewFrame;
                         }];
}
```

}

If someone will find a better way to do this, please let me know. From i will stick with this one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for making custom text bubbles here: [Text Bubbbles](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps). It is slightly old but still applies. I have used it a while ago.

Also here on SO there is a similar question and the second answer looks like a good place for you to start [Speech Buuble in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196112/speech-bubble-in-ios-sdk-using-objective-c)