# iOS 6: Need to add an image and text to screenshot's footer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigraphicscontext

I have a code that makes screenshot from my view

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Currently I am looking around for an approach how to add to the bottom of this ready image logo and text. Some help is much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this answer, it's adding some text to a drawing context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6993766/662605

Essentially you can use `drawInRect:` of `UIImage` with code similar to the code in the link to draw another image into your drawing context.