# Getting Screenshot of certain views to camera roll iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am still a beginner with Objective-C and am hoping someone can help me out.  What I have created programmatically is a `UIScrollView` that has images inside that you can swipe across.  Then I created a `UIButton` that when pressed is supposed to take a screenshot of the image subview the has been selected and then saves it to the camera roll (that part i'm not sure where to add in the code).  The reason I want it to be a screenshot and not just the image is because I will later add `UILabels` on top of the images and I want those to appear in the saved screenshot as well.  I am not quite sure which views to use in the saveWallpaper method and even if my current solution will work.  I have looked at this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically/2203293#2203293) to get the screenshot code to try for this implementation.  Basically I want it to take a screenshot of everything besides the `UIButton` and save it to the camera roll.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.  I could also try an approach where it takes a screenshot or captures certain elements and adds them together to be a single image.  Thank you!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int PageCount = 21;

    NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png",@"10.png",@"11.png",@"12.png",@"13.png",@"14.png",@"15.png",@"16.png",@"17.png",@"18.png",@"19.png",@"20.png",@"21.png", nil];
    scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scroller.bounces = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
    int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
    int xPos=0;
    for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
        width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    }

    UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [saveButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(saveWallpaper:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [saveButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [saveButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"savepressed.png"] forState:     UIControlStateHighlighted];
    saveButton.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, 396, 96.5, 42); //Make this in the center
    [self.view addSubview:saveButton];

}

- (void)saveWallpaper:(id)sender
{

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scroller.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scroller.bounds.size);
        [scroller.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than drawing the complete scroller view as in the following statement

[scroller.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

Draw the selected image and the text using drawInRect method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone) related post for reference.