# Add label and imageview on animated gif and share animated gif

Tags: ios, image, animation, gif, caption

I am working on the picture caption app. For normal png picture all is working fine but my client ask me to create animated gif from the images. i have created animated gif using imageview animation property but the problem comes when i have to add caption on gif image and share that gif image with caption on it.I am sharing simple gif image by convering them into NSdata. Please advice me the right way to add caption on animated gif.
I have used below code to create gif image

```
 CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]),kUTTypeGIF,[camImages count],NULL);
 NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:      [NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:(NSString *)@"0.15f"]
 forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
 NSDictionary *gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount]
 forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

_image=[[UIImage alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<camImages.count;i++)
{
    _image =[camImages objectAtIndex:i];
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, _image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(frameProperties));
}
 CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(gifProperties));
 CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "share animated gif" ?

Comment: We need to share the that animated images as a gif image. So that when that image get opened in Browser it display as gif image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have every frame of the gif, so you can draw the title on every image of the gif on the same position, then you get new images and you will compose them into a new gif.

[How to write text on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone)

It's a rotate text demo.

```
NSString * str = @"hello" ;
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path"] ;
CGSize imageSize = image.size ;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0.0) ;
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)] ;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set] ;
[str drawInRect:CGRectMake(-imageSize.width, -imageSize.height, imageSize.width, imageSize.height) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]] ;
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIImage * compressedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: How can i center align the text when using drawInRect ?

Comment: @Reeps You can try it `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:`, but it is deprecated in ios7.

Comment: Can i rotate text inside image while writing the text on image?