# Add label at certain point on top of an UImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a ViewController that has a UIImageView as a background. What is the proper way to add a label on top of the image if I have the coordinates? My program is adding additional images  on top of the UIImageView with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.myBackground.image.size);

[newImage drawAtPoint: point];

// Draw a textlabel below the new image

// Some additional code
```

I have managed to draw the new Image on top of the original, but I don't know how to add the label.

Hank

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write text on image in objective-c iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

```
[@"YOUR TEXT" drawAtPoint:point withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addSubview: method for UIImageView to add label or any other subview.
Set up label frame to be relative to uiimageview and add it as a subview:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
// To use point you can specify label size and after that you can set center:
label.center = point;
//set up other label properties
[self.myBackground addSubview:label];
//I assume self.myBackground is type of UIImageView
```