# How would I save a photo with text (inputted by a user) that is overlaid onto it?

Tags: swift

The user inputs text into a textfield, they then press a 'go' button and then a label, which is on the photo, presents the text that the user has inputted.

How would the user be able save the photo with the text on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0):

**Overlay text:** Found this SO answer some time ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907826/1465126

**Save image to file:** Save UIImage to file using this tutorial:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation

I've already used this in a project myself, it works.
Hope it helps.