# SCNMaterial with text not appearing over SCNMaterial with image

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I have an SCNNode (made up of an SCNPlane) with an image on it, and I want to put text over the image. I understand that an SCNNode can have different materials. My problem is that I can load an image on the SCNNode, but the text does not appear when I load it. My code looks something like this:

```
let mat = SCNMaterial()
let mat2 = SCNMaterial()
let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 6, length: 9))

mat.diffuse.contents = imgName
mat2.diffuse.contents = strName

node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
node.geometry?.materials = [mat, mat2]
```

(imgName is a UIImage and strName is a String)

And if I try to load the text before the image ([mat2, mat]), I'm just going to get a blank plane. Am I missing a step in preparing the SCNMaterial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying

```
node.geometry?.materials = [mat, mat2]
```

you're saying that the first face of your node should have material `mat`, and the second  face should have material `mat2`(and so on for the 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, etc faces).Since you're working with an `SCNPlane`, that should be its front and back.

Do your compositing of the text over the image outside of SceneKit, so that you have just one image. Or, use the material's `transparent` property for the text (you'll probably want to use `SCNTransparencyMode.RGBZero`) to overlay the image. David Ronnqvist's SceneKit book has nice examples of transparency in the planet examples.

Comment: Your suggestion to modify the image outside of SceneKit made me reconsider my approach. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift) while searching, and incorporated another function into my code that would make a copy of the image for the purpose of adding to that plane only. Now I can see text on my image. Thanks for the point in the right direction.