# WKInterfacePicker -- change textColor

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos-3

Is there an easy solution to change the text color of picker on watchos? Maybe an easy routine with images representing the text?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't change the colour of your text in a `WKInterfacePicker`.

Maybe, you can find solution like this : 
[How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)