# overlaying text on image using swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

I am trying to overlay some text on an image using Swift and am looking at this code here: (src: [How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift#))

This places the text right in the center. I have been changing the values in

```
 var rect = CGRectMake(10,150, inImage.size.width,    
   inImage.size.height)
```

but I am unable to get the text to show in the lower left corner. Can someone help and show what I am missing here ?

I am adding the modified image using this line:

```
modImage = self.textToImage("000", inImage: UIImage(named:"thisImage.png")!, atPoint: CGPointMake(10, 400))
```

Below is the function...

```
func textToImage(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage{

    // Setup the font specific variables
    var textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

    // Setup the image context using the passed image
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inImage.size, false, scale)

    // Setup the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    ]

    // Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image
    inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

    // Create a point within the space that is as bit as the image
    var rect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

    // Draw the text into an image
    drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Pass the image back up to the caller
    return newImage

}
```

Comment: Btw, the orig. thread would not let me post any comments, hence the separate thread. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code where you use this function to add the text to an image.

Comment: You shouldn't change the variable inside the function, it uses the point that you pass to it when calling the function. Do you get the text on the upper left corner of your image if you use this line `modImage = self.textToImage("000", inImage: UIImage(named:"thisImage.png")!, atPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0))`?

Comment: Nope, still shows up in the center of the image.

Comment: Thats odd! For me it's drawing the text at the point that I pass to it as it should. add `print(rect)` after `var rect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)`. What is the output?

Comment: rect is (0.0, 0.0, 3024.0, 4032.0)

Comment: well then I'm out of guesses. if you like you can put your project on github and I'll take a look at it and try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Let me debug a bit further and if it doesn't work I will take up your offer.

Comment: modImage = self.addTextToImage("What is this", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPointMake(400,2800))
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(modImage,0.1)!
This is what finally got the text at the lower left. Wondering if the scaling/conversion is doing something change or it could be the constraints too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Details

xCode 9.1, Swift 4

### Solution

> extension UIView

```
extension UIView {

    func copyObject<T: UIView> () -> T? {
        let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedData) as? T
    }
}
```

> extension UIImage

```
 extension UIImage {

    typealias EditSubviewClosure<T: UIView> = (_ parentSize: CGSize, _ viewToAdd: T)->()

    func with<T: UIView>(view: T, editSubviewClosure: EditSubviewClosure<T>) -> UIImage {

        if let copiedView = view.copyObject() as? T {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

            let basicSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            draw(in: basicSize)
            editSubviewClosure(size, copiedView)
            copiedView.draw(basicSize)

            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return newImage!
        }
        return self

    }
}
```

> extension UIImageView

```
 extension UIImageView {

    enum ImageAddingMode {
        case changeOriginalImage
        case addSubview
        case addCopiedSubview
    }

    func drawOnCurrentImage<T: UIView>(view: T, mode: ImageAddingMode, editSubviewClosure: @escaping UIImage.EditSubviewClosure<T>) {

        guard let image = image else {
            return
        }

        let addSubView: (T) -> () = { view in
            editSubviewClosure(self.frame.size, view)
            self.addSubview(view)
        }

        switch mode {
            case .changeOriginalImage:
                self.image = image.with(view: view, editSubviewClosure: editSubviewClosure)

            case .addSubview:
                addSubView(view)

            case .addCopiedSubview:
                if let copiedView = view.copyObject() as? T {
                    addSubView(copiedView)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

> Sample 1

```
func sample1(label: UILabel) {
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")?.with(view: label) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
        print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
        viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
        viewToAdd.bounds = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 40)
    }
}
```

[image]

> Sample 2

```
func sample2(label: UILabel) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .changeOriginalImage) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
        print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
        viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
        viewToAdd.textAlignment = .right
        let width: CGFloat = 200
        let height: CGFloat = 30
        let indent: CGFloat = 40
        viewToAdd.bounds = CGRect(x: parentSize.width - width - indent, y: parentSize.height - height - indent, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

[image]

> Sample 3

```
func sample3(label: UILabel) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .addSubview) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
        print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
        viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
        viewToAdd.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 20)
    }
}
```

[image]

> Sample 4

```
func sample4(label: UILabel) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .addCopiedSubview) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
        print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
        viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
        viewToAdd.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 20)
    }
}
```

[image]

### Full sample

> Do not forget **to add the solution code here**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 80, height: 30))
        label.text = "Blablabla"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.textColor = .black
        view.addSubview(label)

        sample1(label: label)
        //sample2(label: label)
        //sample3(label: label)
        //sample4(label: label)

        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    func sample1(label: UILabel) {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")?.with(view: label) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
            print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
            viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
            viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
            viewToAdd.bounds = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 20)
        }
    }

    func sample2(label: UILabel) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .changeOriginalImage) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
            print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
            viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
            viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
            viewToAdd.textAlignment = .right
            let width: CGFloat = 200
            let height: CGFloat = 30
            let indent: CGFloat = 40
            viewToAdd.bounds = CGRect(x: parentSize.width - width - indent, y: parentSize.height - height - indent, width: width, height: height)
        }
    }

    func sample3(label: UILabel) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .addSubview) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
            print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
            viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
            viewToAdd.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 20)
        }
    }

    func sample4(label: UILabel) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wall")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.drawOnCurrentImage(view: label, mode: .addCopiedSubview) { (parentSize, viewToAdd) in
            print("parentSize: \(parentSize)")
            viewToAdd.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            viewToAdd.textColor = .yellow
            viewToAdd.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes this works for me too. But in my original project though it doesn't help. I'll debug further, but thanks for this. NEver used extensions before so thats good to know too. Thanks.

Comment: If you need more advice, I'll be happy to help you. I need more of your code, or image that you are getting and how it should be.

Comment: Your code works well the first time, but if I edit again the same image I got memory leaked : "CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 2687385600 bytes for bitmap data"

Comment: This is very strange. I create circle for n=1000 where I add text on 4k photo. Maximum memory usage = 100mb. I need more details. Or create new question with your sample. I will help you.

Comment: I found the dimension and size of the output image are increased by x3. So when I edit twice the image the dimension and size are increased by 9, I guess this explain the memory leaked and crashed.

Comment: FIXED : the problem was the constant "let scale". So I just replaced with "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)"

Comment: No text added to my image. Here is my code:   let image = UIImage(named: "4HV.jpg")!.addText("swift", atPoint: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), textColor:UIColor.white, textFont:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20))

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk How do I add a background color to the label? Adding it in the completion handler of the `with` function does not help

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Vasily!

but in my situation I needed to add these fixes.

**TEXT IS VERY SMALL**

I ran a situation where the text was super small, maybe because the UIImage size was too small for the selected font of 14, so I fixed this by giving a huge font of 120.

**TEXT IS NOT DISPLAYED AT THE GIVEN CGPOINT**

In the same context of a big **UIImage** size, the position given to the extension was misplacing the text, the fix: added these 2 lets with the ratio of height and width computed and then multiplied for x,y points.

```
let widthRatio = size.width/UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let heightRatio = size.height/UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

Hope that helps anybody!