# text draw on image extending off the image

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm using the answer  from [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift) to draw text on an image. The issue I am having is when the CGPoint is set near the right edge of the image, the text extends off of the image. I'm trying to figure out a way to draw left instead of right from the CGPoint or somehow calculate the size in points of the text that will be drawn then then move the draw point to accommodate for this size.

Here is the code I am using.

```
  func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {

    let color = UserDefaults.standard.colorForKey(key: "color")!
    let font = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "font") as! String
    let size = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "size") as! Int
    let fontAndSize = UIFont(name: font, size: CGFloat(size))!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
      NSFontAttributeName: fontAndSize,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
      ] as [String : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
  }

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String {
      if mediaType.isEqual((kUTTypeImage as String)) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
          let width = pickedImage.size.width
          let height = pickedImage.size.height
          // this puts the point in the bottom right of the image which then causes the text drawn to extend off of the image
          let point = CGPoint(x: width - 20, y: height - 50)
          let timestampText = getTimestampText() as NSString
          let timestampImage = textToImage(drawText: timestampText, inImage: pickedImage, atPoint: point)
          if newMedia {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(timestampImage, nil, nil, nil)
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw to the left, you can in fact "calculate the size in points of the text that will be drawn then move the draw point to accommodate for this size" by using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`. Ex:

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {

    let color = UserDefaults.standard.colorForKey(key: "color")!
    let font = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "font") as! String
    let size = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "size") as! Int
    let fontAndSize = UIFont(name: font, size: CGFloat(size))!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: fontAndSize,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
        ] as [String : Any]

    // Calculate text size
    let rectSize = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:CGFloat(MAXFLOAT), height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textFontAttributes, context: nil).size

    // Subtract the text width from the x origin
    let rect = CGRect(x:point.x-rectSize.width, y:point.y, width:rectSize.width, height: rectSize.height)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm also trying to figure out how to draw in the center. For that I modified your rect property to: let rect = CGRect(x:point.x-(rectSize.width / 2), y:point.y, width:rectSize.width, height: rectSize.height). This is giving me the correct x position but the y position is not exactly centered, instead it is a bit below center on the image. Any suggestions on why it is not exactly centered?

Comment: Nevermind! I changed it to let rect = CGRect(x:point.x-(rectSize.width / 2), y:point.y-(rectSize.height / 2), width:rectSize.width, height: rectSize.height) and it is working.

Comment: @chickenparm Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try aligning the text to the right using the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`

```
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.rightTextAlignment

let textFontAttributes = [
  NSFontAttributeName: fontAndSize,
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
  NSParagraphAttributeStyleName: textStyle
  ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Than you for the response. I was not able to get it working exactly as I wanted with your response but I was able to get it working with Lyndsey's response.