# Text animation over Video in Ios

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm able to render a video with AVFoundation from a group of Image but i can't figure out how to put some moving text on bottom from one side to another just like in this simple video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REdz8ZpX3vo&feature=youtu.be". Any suggestion?

Comment: I am also facing the same same issue, please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the images and put the text on them changing the position. Here is one possible solution on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift) for putting text to images