# Save PHAsset to camera roll after edits

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phasset

I have incorporated [this](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker) framework into my app for selecting images from the camera roll. My app allows users to select one or multiple images and add a timestamp String to the image and save the new the image to the users camera roll. Right now it saves the edited images as a new image but I am trying to figure out how to instead update the existing image in the user's camera roll. I know I should be able to do this using the Photos framework released with iOS 8 but I am really struggling. I watched the 2014 WWDC session "Introducing the Photos Framework" but it is in Objective-C and I am having trouble translating.

Here is my code for selecting the image from the camera roll. I get an array of PHAssets.

```
  func selectImageFromCameraRoll(mediaType: String) {
    newMedia = false
    let newImagePicker = BSImagePickerViewController()
    newImagePicker.doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stamp", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: nil)

    bs_presentImagePickerController(newImagePicker, animated: true,
                                    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                      print("Selected")
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
      print("Deselected")
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
      print("Cancel")
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
      for asset in assets {
        self.saveAssetToRoll(asset: asset)
      }
      print("Finished")
    }, completion: nil)
  }
```

Here is my code to save the updated image to the camera roll.

```
  func saveAssetToRoll(asset: PHAsset) {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var pickedImage = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .default, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
      pickedImage = result!})
    let width = pickedImage.size.width
    let height = pickedImage.size.height
    let location = Locations(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "location") as! String)!
    var point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    switch location {
    case .topLeft:
      point = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 50)
    case .topRight:
      point = CGPoint(x: width - 30, y: 50)
    case .bottomLeft:
      point = CGPoint(x: 30, y: height - 50)
    case .bottomRight:
      point = CGPoint(x: width - 30, y: height - 50)
    case .center:
      point = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
    case .topCenter:
      point = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: 50)
    case .bottomCenter:
      point = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height - 50)
    }
    let savedFormat = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "format") as! String
    var date = Date()
    if !currentDateBool {
      date = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedDate") as! Date
    }
    let timestampText = getFormattedDateFromFormatType(formatType: savedFormat, date: date) as NSString
    let timestampImage = textToImage(drawText: timestampText, inImage: pickedImage, atPoint: point)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(timestampImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
  }
```

From reading Apple's documentation it looks like I need to be using a combination of PHContentEditingInput and PHContentEditingOutput. Can someone please point me in the correct direction for incorporating this into my code? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/993848367d9268021783c995887e4b0d16fa3ace/bk2ch17p700PhotoKitImages/PhotoKitImages/DataViewController.swift

Comment: @matt Thanks I will take a look at this!

Comment: You may recall that we already sort of talked about this in connection with your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052024/terminated-due-to-memory-issue-when-saving-altered-image-to-camera-roll