# Is it possible to generate NSImage from string?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsimage

I've seen a couple of solutions on how to generate UIImage with string [How to generate an UIImage from custom text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100121/how-to-generate-an-uiimage-from-custom-text-in-swift/51124297), but replicating the same thing on macOS seems difficult since their Graphic library is different. Please I just need to convert a string to NSImage so I can use it on a mac application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a new NSImage object, lockFocus, draw the attributed string on it and unlockFocus again:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func image(foregroundColor: NSColor? = nil, backgroundColor: NSColor? = nil) -> NSImage {
        let size = self.size()
        let image = NSImage(size: size)
        image.lockFocus()
        let mutableStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        if let foregroundColor = foregroundColor,
           let backgroundColor = backgroundColor {
            mutableStr.setAttributes([.foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
                                      .backgroundColor: backgroundColor],
                                     range: .init(location: 0, length: length))
        }
        else
        if let foregroundColor = foregroundColor {
            mutableStr.setAttributes([.foregroundColor: foregroundColor],
                                     range: .init(location: 0, length: length))
        }
        else
        if let backgroundColor = backgroundColor {
            mutableStr.setAttributes([.backgroundColor: backgroundColor],
                                     range: .init(location: 0, length: length))
        }
        mutableStr.draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
}
```

---

```
let stackOverflow = NSAttributedString(string: "StackOverflow")
stackOverflow.image()
stackOverflow.image(foregroundColor: .red)
stackOverflow.image(backgroundColor: .white)
stackOverflow.image(foregroundColor: .red, backgroundColor: .green)
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func image(foregroundColor: NSColor? = nil, backgroundColor: NSColor? = nil) -> NSImage {
        NSAttributedString(string: .init(self)).image(foregroundColor: foregroundColor, backgroundColor: backgroundColor)
    }
}
```

---

```
"StackOverflow".image()
```

edit/update:

If you would like to create an image from a label (NSTextField)

```
extension NSView {
    var image: NSImage? {
        guard let bitmapImageRep = bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: bounds) else { return nil }
        cacheDisplay(in: bounds, to: bitmapImageRep)
        guard let cgImage = bitmapImageRep.cgImage else { return nil }
        return NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: bounds.size)
    }
}
```

---

```
let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "StackOverflow")
label.textColor = .blue
label.backgroundColor = .clear
label.sizeToFit()
label.image
```