# How to change font size for each segment in UISegmentedControl. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, font-size, uisegmentedcontrol

can i change font sizes for each segment in UISegmentedControll? I know i can change for all, but i want each segment to have different font size. Is it possible?
For example if I have 3 segments I want to have font sizes 10,15,20.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with Strings as segments, but if you were to use Images, it's possible.

First we need a function to convert a String into an image. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991797/964961) by [@NoodleOfDeath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409958/noodleofdeath) on SO gives a nice solution that doesn't involve usage of UIKit controls:

```swift
extension String {
    func image(withAttributes attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil, size: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let size = size ?? (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            (self as NSString).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size),
                                    withAttributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you simply insert images into your UISegmentedControl instead of Strings:

```swift
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: [
    "Paris".image(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)])!,
    "London".image(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)])!,
    "Berlin".image(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])!,
])
```

[image: example]