# How to draw a signature or add an image signature to a PDF in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, draw, pdfkit

By using below code I'm able to load the pdf. Then I have added an add signature button at navigation bar. On click of the add signature button should allow me to browse the signature image then after click the add button it should add the signature on the pdf and back to first view controller.

or in the first view controller when the pdf is displaying how to draw a signature

```
import UIKit 
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { @IBOutlet weak var pdfContainerView: PDFView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "PDF Viewer"
    setupPdfView()
}

func setupPdfView() {
  
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf") {
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
            pdfContainerView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfContainerView.autoScales = true
            pdfContainerView.displayDirection = .vertical
            pdfContainerView.document = pdfDocument
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: [This](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/insert-image-into-pdf-with-swift/) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add file `ImageStampAnnotation.swift`

```
class ImageStampAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
var image: UIImage!

init(with image: UIImage!, forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.stamp,  withProperties: properties)
    self.image = image
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext)   {
    guard let cgImage = self.image.cgImage else { return }
    context.draw(cgImage, in: self.bounds)
}
}
```

set Annotation in current page of pdf

```
func setupPdfView() {
    
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf") {
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
            pdfContainerView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfContainerView.autoScales = true
            pdfContainerView.displayDirection = .vertical
            pdfContainerView.document = pdfDocument
            
            // position of sign image
            let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 35)
            let imageAnnotation = ImageStampAnnotation(with: UIImage(named: "signer"), forBounds: rect, withProperties: nil)
            pdfContainerView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(imageAnnotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's build in pdf preview with build it annotations, which includes the user's signatures as well.
How to implement the **QLPreviewViewController** is explained in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743098/12035498