# PencilKit plus button not showing on ToolPicker

Tags: ios, xcode, canvas, pencilkit

I'm trying to use ToolPicker on my canvas, but here what I have :

[image: mine]

and I want (button + and text, shapes...):
[image: i want]

How can I add Text, shapes to ToolPicker on my canvas ?

```
struct MyCanvas: UIViewRepresentable {
        var canvasView: PKCanvasView
        let picker = PKToolPicker.init()
        
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
            self.canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 15)
            self.canvasView.isOpaque = false
            self.canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    
           let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "badmintoncourt"))
            let subView = self.canvasView.subviews[0]
                subView.addSubview(imageView)
                subView.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
            return canvasView
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
            picker.addObserver(canvasView)
            picker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: uiView)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you found an answer, please let me know, I'm searching for month now for this solution!

Comment: @FrugalResolution did you find solution?

Comment: @Jaydip Indeed I did: It's not build in into the PencilKit. You have to open the file you want to annotate with the QLPreviewViewController. I have explained the process in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743098/12035498