# PKToolPicker add text, shape and signature

Tags: swift, pencilkit

I am not getting any option to add text, shape and signature while markup a photo with PencelKit in my app. This option is available in Apple's Photos App. I have tried to access this with various properties of CanvasView and PKToolPicker, but with no success.

Comment: Please post the code of what you have so far, even if it's very minimal. It's more helpful for others to answer if they can see what you are trying.

Answer (score 2):

It's not build in into the PencilKit. You have to open the file you want to annotate with the **QLPreviewViewController**.
I have explained the process in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743098/12035498