# Add UILabel to image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel

I am creating an image that is then saved to the users camera roll. I would like to add some text to the image. Should I add the string to a UILabel then convert this to an image?

What is your suggestion? Thanks. (I am using Swift)

```
    let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "Image1.png")
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "Image2.png")
    let anotherImage = UIImage(named: "Image3.png")

    let newSize = CGSizeMake(2480, 3508)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

    bottomImage?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width/2, 500))
    topImage?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(newSize.width/2, 0, newSize.width/2, 500), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 0.8)
    anotherImage?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(newSize.width/2, 500, newSize.width/2, 500), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 0.8)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`NSAttributedString drawInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/drawInRect:).

Comment: How do I add the string to the NSAttributedString?

Comment: [`NSAttributedString initWithString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithString:)

Comment: I am trying to change the font using the code below and I am displayed an error message.         `let textFont = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)]
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: titleValue)
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: titleValue, attributes: textFont)` "Extra Argument 'string' in call

Comment: For `attributes` you want to pass a dictionary, so I *think* the swift version of that is `attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : textFont]`.

Comment: I have updated it to the following `let title = NSAttributedString(string: titleValue, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : textFont])` and still have the same message.

Comment: Oh I see `textFont` is a dictionary.  It's hard to read in the comments.  I'm not 100% sure how you would write it in swift.

Comment: Any ideas how to create an attribute for Text Alignment?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone (it's obj c, but the concept is the same)