# How can I add a watermark to an image using this code?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I know there are several other ways to do this; I don't want to import anything that I don't need to. If someone can help me with his code, that would be great.

Currently, it is only saving the original image without the watermark image.

```
extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithWatermark(image1: UIImageView, image2: UIImageView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image1.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        image2.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        image1.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}

func addWatermark() {
    let newImage = UIImage.imageWithWatermark(imageView, image2: watermarkImageView)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

EDIT: I've got the watermark appearing on the saved images.

I had to switch the order of the layers:

```
 image1.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
 image2.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

HOWEVER, it is not appearing in the correct place.It seems to always appear in the center of the image.

Comment: so you want to simply put some text on a image ?

Comment: did u look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone ?

Comment: Sorry, no an image. I want an image on top of another image.

Comment: Why dont you try to place an imageview on imageview and then snapshot it ?

Comment: I'll try that. Maybe I've been overthinking it. Haha thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SWIFT 4**
Use this

```
let backgroundImage = imageData!
let watermarkImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "jodi_url_icon")

let size = backgroundImage.size
let scale = backgroundImage.scale

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
backgroundImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
watermarkImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: size.width, height: size.height - 40))

let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Use result to UIImageView, tested.

Answer (score 16):

If you grab the UIImageViews' images you could use the following concept:

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "image.png"), img2 = UIImage(named: "watermark.png") {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, true, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    img.drawInRect(rect, blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1)
    img2.drawInRect(CGRectMake(x,y,width,height), blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1)

    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(result, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @mrkbxt in

**Swift 5:**

```
func addWatermartToImage (image: UIImage?) {
    if let img = image, let watermarkImg = UIImage(named: "watermark.png") {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, true, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        img.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        watermarkImg.draw(in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 0.6)

        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(result, nil, nil, nil)

    }
}
```