# Swift: I want add labels as overlay to an Image and then I want to share the Image to Social Network

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Swift: I want add labels as overlay to an Image and then I want to share the Image to Social Network.

This is the code sharing the image to social network ..

```
@IBAction func share(sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstActivityItem = "Text you want"
    let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http//:www.google.com")!
    // If you want to put an image
    let image : UIImage = scannedImage.image!

    textToImage("gsdghdhfjhfhgdhdh", inImage: scannedImage.image!, atPoint: CGPointMake(20, 20))

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem, image], applicationActivities: nil)

    // This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)

    // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)

    // Anything you want to exclude
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
          ]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: after set overlay you need to create an image programmatically then you can share this image to social media

Comment: Refer this to make image with text - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone