# Swift 3 - UIImageView image gets shrunk

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

Here is code that prepares-for a segue, and then unwinds from that segue.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toTossImageVC" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! TossImageViewController
        dvc.displayedImage = tossPhoto2.image
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToTossVC(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let dvc = unwindSegue.source as! TossImageViewController
    self.tossPhoto2.image = dvc.displayedImage
}
```

As can be seen, I am passing an image to the destination VC in the prepare for, and then I am retrieving an updated version of that image (the user can tag the image in the destination VC) in the unwind method.

self.tossPhoto2 is a UIImage object and its contentMode is set to scaleToFill in Interface Builder.  My problem is that when I do the unwind and assign tossPhoto2's image to dvc.displayedImage, it gets horribly shrunk.  Before segueing and tagging the image:

[BeforePhotoFine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eadhT.png)

Then, when we return to this VC after tagging the photo with labels, here's the horribly shrunk photo after:

[AfterPhotoShrunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO3wR.png)

After searching StackOverflow and other places for a couple of hours, the best suggestion to solving the problem was to set contentMode to .scaleAspectFit but that didn't work (and I want to keep this as scaleToFill anyway as defined in Interface Builder).

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix this? Here's the code in TossImageViewController if it helps, but I don't see how I might be inadvertently shrinking the image. This could allows the user to add tags (implemented as UILabels) onto the image.

```
class TossImageViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var tossImage: UIImageView!
var displayedImage: UIImage!
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Select Toss Type", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
var selectedTossType = String()
var touchPoint: CGPoint!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tossImage.image = displayedImage

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    // Set up the action sheet picker
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    ac.addAction(cancelAction)
    let trashAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Trash", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Trash"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 80)
        print("Trash tag")
    })
    ac.addAction(trashAction)
    let sinkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sink Disposal", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Sink Disposal"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 120)
    })
    ac.addAction(sinkAction)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save for Later", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Save for Later"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 140)
    })
    ac.addAction(saveAction)
    let animalAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Animal", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Animal"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 80)
    })
    ac.addAction(animalAction)
    let sharingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sharing", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Sharing"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 80)
    })
    ac.addAction(sharingAction)
    let compostAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Compost", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.selectedTossType = "Compost"
        // Write the selected toss type where the tap happened
        self.displayedImage = self.textToImage(drawText: self.selectedTossType as NSString, inImage: self.displayedImage, atPoint: self.touchPoint, labelWidth: 80)
    })
    ac.addAction(compostAction)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint, labelWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (point.x - labelWidth/2), y: point.y, width: labelWidth, height: 20))
    label.textColor = .red
    label.shadowColor = .yellow
    label.text = text as String
    label.textAlignment = .center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let taggedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return taggedImage!
}
```

Comment: The `contentMode` does *not* change the image - it simply changes the way it is **displayed**. I'm guessing that something in `TossImageViewController` is modifying the image and, without you doing so intentionally, is creating a *small* version, and then returning that.

Comment: Understand on contentMode. Per your tip, I inspected image.size throughout the execution of this issue (between both VCs) and it never changes: 3000 wide by 2002 high. Still digging for an answer. I can share the code in TossImageViewController if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - it looks like this is the problem...

You have a `UIImageView` in your `TossImageViewController` - I don't know its size, but let's say it's 300x300. You set its `.image = displayedImage`. So far, so good... you see your image scaled to fit on the screen.

Next, after user interaction, you call `textToImage(...)` and I'm *guessing* you are trying to draw the text *onto* the original image? If so, that's not what's happening.

Instead, you are adding a `UILabel` to `self.view`, creating a Graphics Context of `3000 x 2002`, and then returning `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` ... but that image is the current view - which is perhaps `750 x 1334` and sitting in the upper-left corner of the Context.

What you need to do is, either:

a) create a `3000 x 2002` UIView, add the image in a UIImageView as a subview of that view, then add the UILabel (sized relative to the big image) as another subview. Then get the image from *that* context. Or...

b) use the Context and image drawInRect and string drawInRect functions.

This post has some discussion and solutions (both Obj-C and Swift): [How to write text on image in Objective-C (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-ios)

Comment: Thank you! This got me over the hump -- I ended up following the discussion in the link you provided and I'm now (very close) to getting the exact behavior I'm looking for. I really appreciate it!

Comment: DonMag - In following the code in the SO post you linked to, I can get things working without shrinking the image, all good there.  But now the text isn't showing up where the user taps, as I describe in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580224/swift-3-nsstring-drawin-rect-withattributes-text-not-being-drawn-at-ex. Any thoughts on why that is happening?